# Unity Particle System cannot appear in game scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have problems with my unity particle system. It is appearing in the scene but it does not appear in the game scene after it is being played. What do you think the problem lies in?

Comment: Does it have `Looping` and `Play on awake` settings enabled?

Comment: I have them both enabled but it is still not working.

Answer (score 4):

1.ParticleSystem is not loop, not enable or not play...
2.Your particles are too small.
3.Particles are not in the camera's view.
4.If you are using Unity's 2D tool, maybe sprite's sorting order is above your particle. <- Change ParticleSystem's sortingLayerName and sortingOrder.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a bug where the particle's origin (usually the centre) is well outside the camera's frustum they can be incorrectly culled.  I found this with giant sunbeams.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  The problem for me ended up being related to the Renderer Module's "Render Alignment" being set to "World".  Pair this with -90 rotation on X and it made my particles disappear (2D game with an orthographic camera probably didn't help).  Switching Render Alignment to "Facing" fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to check is the Z positioning of the Particle System and any parents. In my case I had accidentally set the Z position to a value that placed it behind the main camera